# CalendarContracts: column 'method' is invalid

Tags: android, uri, google-calendar-api

Ok so guys i made an app that add events in google calendar and it worked fine but after that i wanted to add a reminder so i put the code for reminders but when I tested it i got the error: `column 'method' is invalid`

Here is my code:

```
                       `ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                        long startMillis = 0;
                        long endMillis = 0;
                        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                        beginTime.set(EndAn, EndLuna, EndZi, EndOra, 00);
                        startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
                        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                        endTime.set(EndAn, EndLuna, EndZi, EndOra, 10);
                        endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

                        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
                        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, headline);
                        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Description");

                        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
                        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());

                        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);

                        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
                        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
                        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 23);
                        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, 4);
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stringPermission , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

                            Uri uriContent = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
                            String[] projection = new String[]{
                                    CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,
                                    CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                                    CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,
                                    CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME,
                                    CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR,
                                    CalendarContract.Reminders._ID,
                                    CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES,
                                    CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD
                            };

                            Cursor calendarCursor = managedQuery(uriContent, projection, null, null, null);

                        }`
```

So can you tell me what i did wrong/i need to add/delete/modify so that it will work?

P.S: Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

If you read [Reminders and Notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders), then you'd know that your 'method' error was due to this line:

```
 CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD
```

The delivery method to use (see [Delivery mechanisms](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders#delivery_mechanisms)):

- **Pop-up**. These are supported on mobile platforms and on web clients.
- **Email** sent by the server.
- **SMS**. These are only available for G Suite customers.

So try using:

```
 CalendarContract.Reminders.Email or 
 CalendarContract.Reminders.SMS or 
 CalendarContract.Reminders.Pop-up
```

(I'm not sure with the correct Java format)

Comment: in the projection or if statement?